# Error bd Oracle y C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Al tratar de conectar una base de datos Oracle a Visual Studio 2015 me lanza el siguiente error:

> BadImageFormatException. This will occur when running in 64 bit mode
>   with the 32 bit Oracle client components installed.

revise las versiones pero el error persiste :c

Comment: Hola Nicky, con lo que nos comentas no podemos ayudarte, puedes indicarnos como haces la conexión?

Answer (score 1):

El error esta claro, el componente de oracle tiene problemas con la versión 64 bits.
El tema principal pasa porque estas trabajando en un sistema de 64 bits e instalastes un ODAC de 32 bits y no el de 64 bits.